# How to push a sub document inside an array in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to add an array of steps inside a topic. but every time I make a post request. It stores an empty array with an _id only.
here is my model:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
//const Step = require('./Step');

const StepSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    status: String,
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

const TopicSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    description: String,
    steps: [StepSchema],
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Topic', TopicSchema);
```

Here is my router.js:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Topic = require('../models/Topic');

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const topic = new Topic({
        name: req.body.name,
        description: req.body.description,
    });
    topic.steps.push({
        title: req.body.title,
        status: req.body.status
    })
    try {
        const saveTopic = await topic.save();
        res.json(saveTopic);
    } catch (err) {
        res.json({ message: err });
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

here is my postman request:

```
{
    "name": "t",
    "description": "y",
    "steps": {
        "title": "a",
        "status": "b"
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your POSTMAN request, title and status are enclosed in `steps` object.

You need to do:

```
topic.steps.push({
    title: req.body.steps.title,
    status: req.body.steps.status
});
```

instead of:

```
topic.steps.push({
    title: req.body.title,
    status: req.body.status
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also had to change my postman request.
`{
 "name": "t",
 "description": "y",
 "steps": {
  "title": "a",
  "status": "b"
 }
}`

thanks again!